# Sass mixin not exporting/importing prefixes

Tags: css, sass

I want to do a simple sass mixin for background gradient:

```
@mixin primary-gradient {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, #41bfb8, #1e989f);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, #41bfb8, #1e989f);
  background: radial-gradient(to top left, #41bfb8, #1e989f);
  background: #41bfb8;
}
```

This mixin compiled like this:

[image]

Where did the `background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, #41bfb8, #1e989f);` go? am I missing something?

Comment: You probably have some process cleaning up unnecessary prefixes on compilation. You should check your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's your configuration that removes some prefixed properties, maybe with PostCSS.

Try my CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/ZEGLJMG) it's work.

I've inverted the background so it can be overwritten by the gradient.

```
@mixin primary-gradient {
  background: #41bfb8;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, #41bfb8, #1e989f);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, #41bfb8, #1e989f);
  background: radial-gradient(to top left, #41bfb8, #1e989f);
}
```

Comment: I am just using Live sass compiler vscode plugin, tried all their configs and nothing still works.